# Is there a way that just the host can invite a player

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I want to know if there is a way for ONLY the host to invite to a game not other players inviting ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of you're platform, but from experience, I know that on PC there is an option, when creating the game, to allow or disallow others from sending invites... I believe it is something like: "Allow Player Invites" or something along those lines!